# filter hasOne relation laravel with roles on model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using [spatie laravel-permission](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction) and I want to associate my `Muse` model with my `User` model

The main idea is retrieve all users with muse role, that users with muse role can be retrieved using de `Muse` model

My `Muse` model

```
namespace Modules\Admin\Entities;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class Muse extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use HasRoles;

    protected $fillable = [
        'posts_counter',
        'posts_sales_counter',
        'posts_comments_counter',
        'posts_saves_counter',
        'posts_points_counter',
        'user_id'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id');
    }
}
```

I want to filter `users` by `muse` role on my relation, because if I do this query

```
Muse::query()->with('user')->get();
```

I get all because that users are never filtered by muse role on the relation

Comment: `->with()` does not do any kind of filtering to your `Muse` model; you need to use `has()` or `whereHas()` (or their inverse, `doesntHave()` or `whereDoesntHave()`): https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: @TimLewis I need that relation, that relation needs to be filtered by roles anytime, that's why I'm looking for filter on model

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here then... You probably need to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73039461/edit) and include your `Muse` model, or provide more details.

Comment: Yup! But I still don't quite understand what your question is... You say *"I want to filter users by muse role"*, but the query you're doing is backwards; `Muse::with('user')->get()` will return all `muse` rows, with their attached `user`. If you wanted all Users with `Muse` role, you'd do `User::has('muse')->get()` (assuming you defined a `public function muse()` method on your `User` model). Is that what you mean?

Comment: the problem is that when I do the query ```Muse::with('user')->get()``` it doesn't return me all the data from the muse table, it returns me all the data from the users table, including those who aren't muses, that's what I don't understand because those users aren't even in the muses table. That's why I try to filter from the relationship that the users has the muse role

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, unless this package is trying to do something behind the scenes... Laravel guesses the table name from the model name, so `Muse` should be `muses`, or you can specify it via `protected $table = 'muses';` on your `Muse` model. I'll look through the docs on this package, see if I can see anything (disclosure, I haven't used it before, so I'm not sure what it does/how it works).

Comment: My error, on my muse model I didn't pass the localKey, I updated the relation to ```return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'user_id');``` and it works :)